# I need help implementing Autocomplete from antdesign ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i'm still learning and having some trouble understanding the syntax of the [autocomplete][1] from ant design framework ( [1]: https://ant.design/components/auto-complete/)

I need the user to search some value, and then the component will show a suggestions list based on what objects i have
So i wrote the logic to that search,put some fixed value as a const to text and it works
but now i can't understand how to substitute the input value in my logic and how to show the options on the autocomplete component.

here's the call

```
    const [proceds,setProceds] = useState([])
    const text = 'aparelho'
  
    useEffect(() => {
    const loadProceds = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('myapi_url'); 
      setProceds([...res.data]) 
    }
    loadProceds();
      
  },[])
  let results = proceds.filter((proced) => 
    proced.terminologia.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
  );
  console.log(results);
```

in this case it searchs the text and shows which objcs in my api contains it .

my autocomplete blank template is like this

```
function handleChange(value) {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);
  }
  
  

  const Complete = () => (
    <AutoComplete
     style={{ width: 120 }} 
     dropdownMenuStyle={{ maxHeight: 1000, overflowY: 'visible' }} 
     onChange={handleChange}      
     >
       
    </AutoComplete>
  );

  return (
    <>
   <Complete />
    </>
```